# How to setup manual fail over (PROD to DR) in IKS?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, cloudflare, iks

We have  two IBM kubernetes cluster whenever issue happens in one cluster we need to failover to DR. Can anyone tell me how to  do that automatically ? both cluster present in two different zones Montreal & torento. Also we have IBM Cloud internet service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the CIS service Global Load Balancer offering to set up a globally load-balanced and health-checked URL for your applications. You'd create a GLB for domain app.mydomain.com/app_path for example and then back it with the VIPs for your cluster ALBs in the same origin pool. Configure a health check at the GLB so traffic will be sent to the available endpoints that are healthy.

CIS GLB docs are covered at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cis?topic=cis-global-load-balancer-glb-concepts